# Как исправить Call to a member function formName() on null?

Tags: yii2

Call to a member function formName() on null

index.php

```
[code]<?php

use common\models\HistoryBalance;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ListView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel backend\models\HistoryBalanceSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'History Balances');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<?= $this->render('new'), [
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
]; ?>
[/code]
```

new.php
[code]

```
<?php

use common\models\HistoryBalance;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\helpers\Html;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel backend\models\HistoryBalanceSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

?>
<div class="history-balance-index">

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            ['attribute' => 'user_id',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                    return $model->user->username;
                }
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'balance',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                    return $model->balance . '<br>
                        <span class="text-success">' . $model->credit . '</span>';
                }
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'balance_up',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                    return Html::tag('span', $model->balance_up . '<br>' . $model->credit_up . (($model->credit_up >= 0)), [
                        'class' => ($model->credit_up >= 0) ? 'text-success' : 'text-danger'
                    ]);
                }
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'type',
                'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList(
                    $searchModel,
                    'type',
                    HistoryBalance::getSortLabels(),
                    [
                        'everyday' => 'каждый день',
                        'class' =>
                            'form-control form-control-sm'
                    ]
                ),
            ],
            'comment',
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

[/code]

HistoryBalanceController.php
[code]

```
<?php

namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use common\models\HistoryBalance;
use backend\models\HistoryBalanceSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * HistoryBalanceController implements the CRUD actions for HistoryBalance model.
 */
class HistoryBalanceController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
    /**
     * Lists all HistoryBalance models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new HistoryBalanceSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    public function actionNew()
    {
        $searchModel = new HistoryBalanceSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('new', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
}
```

[/code]

Comment: Попробуйте для начал исправить index.php. У вас в метод render вторым параметром должен принимать массив, а он у вас отдельно.

Вот так должно быть:
<?= $this->render('new', [
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
]); ?>

Answer (score 0):

В index.php есть опечатка.
должно быть так

```
<?php

use common\models\HistoryBalance;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ListView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel backend\models\HistoryBalanceSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'History Balances');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<?= $this->render('new', [
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
]); ?>
```

Дополните описание проблемы стектрейсом если это исправление не поможет.